# Visual Studio not showing the directory in Filter account

Tags: azure-active-directory, visual-studio-2019

I'm not able to find the correct Azure active directory in Apply filter/Filter account -window. AAD settings should be fine and I can see tens of other directories, but not this particular one that I need to connect to the DevOps-project. Any ideas where to search for solution?

[Apply filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tjO1.png)

I have tried to restart VS, logged out and login, Checked AAD user settings and compared to the colleague's settings which seems to be similar. No success.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, AAD invitation wasn't accepted. So it was pending and after approval the directory showed up.